# Slide out vertical navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put the finishing touches on this slide out navigation but am running into one final problem.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/93chsw11/1/

Although you should know, it's missing Glyphicons so it doesn't look as good on there, the left of each link has an icon and is clickable to open that section of links. You can still click the right side of the empty space, though.

Now, the problem is that when the navigation is open the content becomes horizontally scrollable and if you scroll to the right it goes on top of the nav bar.

I would like it to either scroll with the navigation, keeping them side by side, or somehow scroll underneath the nav bar. I've looked all around for solutions but nothing fixes this problem without causing another problem.

I'm open to other suggestions of maybe different routes to take, maybe with margins instead of left position or something along those lines? I just want it to look how it does now, with the Glyphicons to the left of the section names, and when the nav is collapsed to show the icons.

Thanks in advance for any and all help :)

CSS for navigation positioning:

```
#sidebar {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
   color: #F0F0F0;
   background-color: #2D5B81;
   padding-top: 40px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

CSS for content positioning:

```
#newcontent {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #fff;
   left: 50px;
   top: 50px;
   width: 96%;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-top: 5px;
}
```

jQuery functions for opening/closing:

```
    $("#hide-nav").click(function() {
        $("#newcontent").animate({'left':"50px"}, 250);
        $(".sublinks").hide(250);
    });

    $(".openall").click(function(){
        $("#newcontent").animate({"left": "205px"}, 250);
        $(".sublinks").show(250);
    });

    $(".hideall").click(function(){
        $(".sublinks").hide(250);
    });

    $(".navLink").click(function() {
        $("#newcontent").animate({"left": "205px"}, 250);
        //$("#newcontent").animate({'marginLeft':"205px"}, 250);
        $(this).parent().children(".sublinks").slideToggle(250, function() {
            $(this).parent().children(".sublinks").toggleClass('sublinks-active');
        });
    });
```

Comment: The mandatory code validator is there for a reason - if jsfiddle goes down (as it frequently does) this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Sorry, it's just there's quite a bit there and I don't want to add it all, I'll edit to include the CSS parts that are probably where the issue can be resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you're trying to do using `z-index` over here coupled with a little of jQuery. You can set the `z-index` of your `sidebar` to a high value such as `9999` when the `openall` button is cicked and you can set the `z-index` back to `0` when the sidebar is hidden. These are the two jQuery functions that I've modified a little in your code:

```
$("#hide-nav").click(function() {
    $("#newcontent").animate({'left':"30px"}, 250);
    $(".sublinks").hide(250);
    $("#sidebar").css("z-index","0");
});

$(".openall").click(function(){
    $("#newcontent").animate({"left": "205px"}, 250);
    $(".sublinks").show(250);
    $("#sidebar").animate({"z-index": "99999"}, 250);
});
```

```js
$("#hide-nav").click(function() {
      $("#newcontent").animate({
        'left': "30px"
      }, 250);
      $(".sublinks").hide(250);
      $("#sidebar").css("z-index", "0");
    });

    $(".openall").click(function() {
      $("#newcontent").animate({
        "left": "205px"
      }, 250);
      $(".sublinks").show(250);
      $("#sidebar").animate({"z-index": "99999"}, 250);
    });

    $(".hideall").click(function() {
      $(".sublinks").hide(250);
    });

    $(".navLink").click(function() {
      $("#newcontent").animate({
        "left": "205px"
      }, 250);
      $(this).parent().children(".sublinks").slideToggle(250, function() {
        $(this).parent().children(".sublinks").toggleClass('sublinks-active');
      });
    });
```

```css
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  /*margin-left: -150px;*/
  color: #F0F0F0;
  background-color: #2D5B81;
  padding-top: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#open-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
#open-close span {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#hide-nav {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -27px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}
#nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navBG {
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #6c8ca6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6c8ca6;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.navLink {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: #d5dee5;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: 550;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navLink:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.navGlyph {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  float: left;
}
.sublinks {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
  color: #c0cdd9;
  background-color: #285174;
}
.sublinks li {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid #6c8ca6;
}
.sublinks li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
.sublinks li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c0cdd9;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.sublinks li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.sublinks-active {
  display: block;
}
#newcontent {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 96%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
#newContent::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
  <nav id="nav">
    <li id="open-close">
      <span class="openall">+</span>
      <span class="hideall">-</span>
    </li>

    <span id="hide-nav">Close</span> 
    <li class="navBG">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navLink">
          General Info
        </a>
      <ul class="sublinks">
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Employee Directory</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Documents</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;FTP</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;CNC Bulletin Board</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Manage</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navBG">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navLink">
          Job Info
        </a>
      <ul class="sublinks">
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Job List</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Files Required</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Incoming Data List</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Signoffs</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Leader List</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Milestone/Timelines</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navBG">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navLink">
          QIR Info
        </a>
      <ul class="sublinks">
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Open QIRs</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Search QIRs</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navBG">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navLink">
          Reports
        </a>
      <ul class="sublinks">
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Tryout Reports</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;R&amp;D Reports</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Tech. Advancements</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;Budget Reports</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;R&amp;D Job Summary</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navBG">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navLink">
          NEW
        </a>
      <ul class="sublinks">
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;New Job</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;New Incoming</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;New Quote</li>
        <li>&ndash; &nbsp;New Program</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="newcontent">
  CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/93chsw11/12/)**.

You can see in the above example that once the sidebar is open, you can scroll horizontally and sidebar always stays on the top and the content scrolls underneath it.

Comment: This works, but when the nav opens there isn't a smooth transition anymore. It just pops open and the content slides out afterwards. Is there any way to do this while keeping the same effect as before?

Comment: @noelllll Yes, there is. Please check my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing the "fixed" nature of the sidebar, you can set the sidebar and content divs to inline-block, then animate the width of the sidebar when closing/opening.

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/93chsw11/14/

Here's what that would look like CSS wise:

```
#sidebar {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
   /*margin-left: -150px;*/
   color: #F0F0F0;
   background-color: #2D5B81;
   padding-top: 40px;
   overflow: auto;
}

#sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

#open-close {
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-top: -10px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   font-size: 0.8em;
}

#open-close span {
   padding: 10px;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

#hide-nav {
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 0.7em;
   font-weight: 600;
   margin-top: -40px;
   margin-left: -27px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   float: right;
}

#nav li {
   list-style-type: none;
}

.navBG {
   padding-right: 20px;
   border-top: 1px solid #6c8ca6;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #6c8ca6;
   margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.navLink {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   color: #d5dee5;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-left: 20px;
   font-weight: 550;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.navLink:hover {
   color: #fff;
}

.navGlyph {
   margin-right: 20px;
   margin-left: 7px;
   float: left;
}

.sublinks {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   margin-top: 5px;
   display: none;
   color: #c0cdd9;
   background-color: #285174;
}

.sublinks li {
   cursor: pointer;
   border-left: 1px solid #6c8ca6;
}

.sublinks li:hover {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}

.sublinks li a {
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #c0cdd9;
   padding: 5px;
   padding-left: 0;
   margin-right: 10px;
}

.sublinks li a:hover {
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: 500;
}

.sublinks-active {
   display: block;
}

#newcontent {
   background-color: #fff;
   height: 100%;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-top: 5px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}

#newContent::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("#hide-nav").click(function() {
    $(this).add(".hideall").hide();
    $("#sidebar").animate({width: "30px"},250);
    $(".sublinks").hide(250);
});

$(".openall").click(function(){
    $("#hide-nav").add(".hideall").show();        
    $("#sidebar").animate({width: "200px"},250);        
    $(".sublinks").show(250);
});

$(".hideall").click(function(){
    $(".sublinks").hide(250);
});

$(".navLink").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".sublinks").slideToggle(250, function() {
        $(this).parent().children(".sublinks").toggleClass('sublinks-active');
    });
});
```